# How to delete the SQL Database from emulator

Tags: android, database

When i deploy my app to Emulator in Android the DB will also get deployed. If i do any changes to DB it will not get deployed again to Emulator. To do this, everytime i have to delete the Emulator from device manager and create new one. This process is really annoying, any idea of  how to delete the DB from Emulator and deploy new one.

Answer (score 2):

you just need to increase the version of the data base which you provide in constructor or the class extending the SQLIteOpenHelper......

and override onUpgrade in  SQLIteOpenHelper :

```
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
  if (newVersion > oldVersion)
    Log.v("Database Upgrade", "Database version higher than old.");
  myContext.deleteDatabase(DB_NAME);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

easier:

open DDMS prespective (menu windows >> open new prespective )

select file explore tag.

then go to data > data > pakage_name> databases> data_base_name.

and delete

Answer (score 1):

follow these steps:

DDMS > select emulater from left side panel

from right handside choose filexplorer > choose your application package
click on databse foder
select your database 
and delete it from top right handside ("red color minus") delete button

Answer (score 0):

Quick and easy:

```
 context.deleteDatabase(DATABASE_NAME);
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than deleting emulator delete the database from

**ddms----> file explorer ----> data/data/your_package_name--->databases
--->yourdatabase .**

and delete it.

and you can do one more thing

simply uninstall the application and install it again , this will remove the database 
and shall create the database again.

Answer (score 0):

one more way if u want to delete database just drop table and again recreate table again as shown below  where

```
String Droptable="drop table if exists item_master"; // where item_master is table name 
myDataBase.execSQL(Droptable);
```

after dropping it recreate it as

```
 String Createtable="CREATE TABLE \"item_master\" (\"item_id\" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL  UNIQUE , \"item_name\" VARCHAR, \"item_img\" VARCHAR, \"item_s_desc\" TEXT, \"item_desc\" TEXT, \"item_map\" VARCHAR, \"bookmark\" VARCHAR DEFAULT N, \"category_id\" INTEGER)"; 

 myDataBase.execSQL(Createtable);
```

you can chnage column name or add or remove column according to ur requirement